# UHD Graphics 630 driver for windows server 2016

Tags: drivers, windows-server-2016

I need device driver by hardware id "PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_9BC8&SUBSYS_D0001458&REV_03
".
I download several driver for this device but it can not run.
Always get error message that this software is not compatible with device.

How to solve this?

Comment: What is the device?  Is it new enough to have a driver for your server?

Comment: Looks like an Intel graphics device. As John says, what's the specific device you're trying to install?

Comment: GIGA H510M S2H . Display adaptor

Comment: That appears to be a workstation.  Try a different operating system and put Server 2016 into a virtual machine.

Comment: @John  No I can not. This system is server

Comment: Try using VGA and a VGA monitor.

Comment: Make and model of PC?

Comment: @John  Monitor is not connect to pc

Comment: @ Moab  GIGA H510M S2H, Intel Core I5 10400, 2TB TOSHIBA V300, 2X 8GB CURSIAL 2666MHz, Graphic On board

Comment: Server 2016 is still in support. Perhaps raise a case with Microsoft Server Support people.